# Java Error net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: unexpected token: ; required: (

Tags: java, sql

My code :

```
try{
    //get DB Connection
    dbConnect = DatabaseConnection.dbConnect();

    //creating statement
    getTableDataStatement = dbConnect.createStatement();
    String getTableData = "SELECT table_available FROM table;";
    ResultSet rs = getTableDataStatement.executeQuery(getTableData);

    //geting value
    while(rs.next()){
        //tableNoFromDb.add(rs.getInt("tableNo"));
        tableStatus.add(rs.getString("table_available"));
    }

    //close everything
    rs.close();
    getTableDataStatement.close();
    dbConnect.close();   

} catch(SQLException se) {
    se.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm able to initialize a connection to db, but i keep getting this error. Tried to remove the ; still got error

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: are you getting data when you execute the same query in database? SELECT table_available FROM table. Issue would be additional ; in select query if you get the data in database.

Comment: Thanks Thilo, i changed the table name and got it fix, put it as answer so i can vote it :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you called your table `table`, which can only cause problems.

Please use a name that is not a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I was Suffering with same problem
My problem is `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSqlException: unexpected token:)`

I was putting one extra ","(comma) with in a SQL statement When I have Removed extra comma It work properly

### **Wrong SQL Statement**

```
String sql="insert into ApplyForLeaveResult(User_ID,Leave_Type,Start_Date,End_Date,Total,Reason,Status,Command) values('"+User_ID1+"','"+Leave_Type1+"','"+Start_Date1+"','"+End_Date1+"','"+Total1+"','"+Reason1+"','"+Status1+"','"+Command1+"',)";
```

### **Correct SQL Statemet**

```
String sql="insert into ApplyForLeaveResult(User_ID,Leave_Type,Start_Date,End_Date,Total,Reason,Status,Command) values('"+User_ID1+"','"+Leave_Type1+"','"+Start_Date1+"','"+End_Date1+"','"+Total1+"','"+Reason1+"','"+Status1+"','"+Command1+")";
```